# UIbutton misplaced in simulator

Tags: ios, button, uiview, swift3

Here I have to implement the UIView for both the screens iPhone 5 and 6. So I used the screeHeight to integrate the UIView. But the button in the view is misplaced in iPhone 5s simulator and works fine in iPhone 6 simulator Here is the code for that. Whatever I changed the values in x and y remains the same top position.

[image: UIView and button in that view are misplaced]

```
if screenHeight == 568{

        self.viewFareEstimate.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:150, width:359, height:40)

    }
```

Comment: apply constraint to button according to your need.

Comment: Solution is present in this doc -> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Answer (score 0):

The screen size of Iphone 5 is 320 × 568, but your width is more than 320.
Try this

```
if screenHeight == 568{

    self.viewFareEstimate.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:150, width:320, height:40)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @imac for good programming practices try to avoid to give constant values to frame.

For your refrence height for iPhone 5 is 568.0f & 6 is 667.0f are different,

&

Whenever you want size width full then try to give frame like this,

```
self.viewFareEstimate.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:150, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height:40);// Manage width by + or - constant value now.
```

In your case check that if you are giving constraint from storyboard already then it should work with setting frame only.